# Why there have delay of change of width while rotating iOS device which running my App

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am building a iOS App with Swift and SwiftUI. I test the device rotating animation for many times since I want it support the landscape mode. I found the changing width of ContentView(or any child views) has delay while rotating Device that cause the BLACK SIDE showing in a flash.

How to fix it?

```
@main
struct TESTApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
           ContentView()
        }
    }
}

// ContentView
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
        
            Rectangle()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Rotating]

As you can see, I had set the Rectangle foreground(or background) to Blue and set the width by using GeometryReader like`.frame(width: geo.size.width)`, it should auto resize the width or height while the Parent changing. But in rotating, the width can't expand on realtime, that's why we can see the black background in there.

I already tried `.ignoresSafeArea()`, it Won't work.

So how to fix it?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `.id()` modifier to your GeometryReader to force the layout update during the device rotation. Assign a unique ID based on the width and height of the screen, which will change when the device is rotated. Here's the updated code:

```
@main
struct TESTApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

// ContentView
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
        
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: geo.size.width)
                .background(Color.blue)
                
        }.id(UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait ? "Portrait" : "Landscape")
    }
}
```

When the device rotates, the ID will change, causing SwiftUI to recreate the view and adapt to the new orientation quickly. This should help to prevent the black side from appearing during the rotation animation.

Comment: It's not working and bring new weird animation. I think the reason is  adding the `.id()` is force to create new View when id change not update existed view itself.

Comment: I see. Can you try to add .ignoresSafeArea() after GeometryReader? Ignore .id() implementation.